# Android project using httpclient --> http.client (apache), post/get method

Tags: java, android, http, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm doing a Get and Post method for an android project and I need to "translate" HttpClient 3.x to HttpClient 4.x (using by android).
My problem is that I'm not sure of what I have done and I don't find the "translation" of some methods...

This is the HttpClient 3.x I have done and (-->) the HttpClient 4.x "translation" if I have found it (Only parties who ask me problems) :

```
HttpState state = new HttpState (); --> ?

HttpMethod method = null; --> HttpUriRequest httpUri = null;

method.abort(); --> httpUri.abort(); //httpUri is a HttpUriRequest

method.releaseConnection(); --> conn.disconnect(); //conn is a HttpURLConnection

state.clearCookies(); --> cookieStore.clear(); //cookieStore is a BasicCookieStore

HttpClient client = new HttpClient(); --> DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

client.getHttpConnectionManager().getParams().setConnectionTimeout(SOCKET_TIMEOUT) --> HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(param, SOCKET_TIMEOUT);

client.setState(state); --> ?

client.getParams().setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.RFC_2109); --> HttpClientParams.setCookiePolicy(param, CookiePolicy.RFC_2109);

PostMethod post = (PostMethod) method; --> ?

post.setRequestHeader(...,...); --> conn.setRequestProperty(...,...);

post.setFollowRedirects(false); --> conn.setFollowRedirects(false);

RequestEntity tmp = null; --> ?

tmp = new StringRequestEntity(...,...,...); --> ?

int statusCode = client.executeMethod(post); --> ?

String ret = method.getResponsBodyAsString(); --> ?

Header locationHeader = method.getResponseHeader(...); --> ?

ret = getPage(...,...); --> ?
```

I don't know if that is correct.
This has caused problems because the packages are not named similarly, and some methods too.
I just need documentation (I haven't found) and little help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest way to answer my question is to show you the class that I made :

```
public class HTTPHelp{

    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
    private boolean abort;
    private String ret;

    HttpResponse response = null;
    HttpPost httpPost = null;

    public HTTPHelp(){

    }

    public void clearCookies() {

        httpClient.getCookieStore().clear();

    }

    public void abort() {

        try {
            if(httpClient!=null){
                System.out.println("Abort.");
                httpPost.abort();
                abort = true;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("HTTPHelp : Abort Exception : "+e);
        }
    }

    public String postPage(String url, String data, boolean returnAddr) {

        ret = null;

        httpClient.getParams().setParameter(ClientPNames.COOKIE_POLICY, CookiePolicy.RFC_2109);

        httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        response = null;

        StringEntity tmp = null;        

        httpPost.setHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux " +
            "i686; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20061201 Firefox/2.0.0.6 (Ubuntu-feisty)");
        httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "text/html,application/xml," +
            "application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5");
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        try {
            tmp = new StringEntity(data,"UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            System.out.println("HTTPHelp : UnsupportedEncodingException : "+e);
        }

        httpPost.setEntity(tmp);

        try {
            response = httpClient.execute(httpPost,localContext);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            System.out.println("HTTPHelp : ClientProtocolException : "+e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("HTTPHelp : IOException : "+e);
        } 
                ret = response.getStatusLine().toString();

                return ret;
                }
}
```

I used [this tutorial](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/) to do my post method and [thoses examples](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/examples.html)

Comment: The second link moved to https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/examples.html

Comment: The first link moved to https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/

Answer (score 23):

Here are the [HttpClient 4 docs](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html), that is what Android is using (4, not 3, as of 1.0->2.x). The docs are hard to find (thanks Apache ;)) because HttpClient is now part of HttpComponents (and if you just look for HttpClient you will normally end up at the 3.x stuff).

Also, if you do any number of requests you do not want to create the client over and over again. Rather, as the [tutorials for HttpClient note](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html#d4e604), create the client once and keep it around. From there use the [ThreadSafeConnectionManager](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/conn/tsccm/ThreadSafeClientConnManager.html).

I use a helper class, for example something like [HttpHelper](http://code.google.com/p/and-bookworm/source/browse/trunk/src/com/totsp/bookworm/data/HttpHelper.java) (which is still a moving target - I plan to move this to its own Android util project at some point, and support binary data, haven't gotten there yet), to help with this. The helper class creates the client, and has convenience wrapper methods for get/post/etc. Anywhere you USE this class from an [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html), you should create an internal inner [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) (so that you do not block the UI Thread while making the request), for example:

```
    private class GetBookDataTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
      private ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(BookScanResult.this);

      private String response;
      private HttpHelper httpHelper = new HttpHelper();

      // can use UI thread here
      protected void onPreExecute() {
         dialog.setMessage("Retrieving HTTP data..");
         dialog.show();
      }

      // automatically done on worker thread (separate from UI thread)
      protected Void doInBackground(String... urls) {
         response = httpHelper.performGet(urls[0]);
         // use the response here if need be, parse XML or JSON, etc
         return null;
      }

      // can use UI thread here
      protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
         dialog.dismiss();
         if (response != null) {
            // use the response back on the UI thread here
            outputTextView.setText(response);
         }
      }
   }
```

Comment: Even better than my HttpHelper is the one the ZXing project uses - http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/android/src/com/google/zxing/client/android/AndroidHttpClient.java.  A little more difficult to work with (though still pretty easy), and more capable. (And I noticed it AFTER I had been using the one I wrote for a long time, similar approach, though not identical, but convergent, not copied. ;).)

Comment: The HTTP client docs have moved — now at: http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html

Comment: Keep in mind that mine is a fairly old answer here, and I haven't updated that helper project in a while (I intend to, just haven't gotten to it). As of API level 8, Android has it's own helper: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/http/AndroidHttpClient.html

Comment: Also note the recommendations from the Android team have changed. They now recommend the standard java.net stuff over HttpClient. For a good wrapper library for HttpURLConnection see this: https://github.com/kevinsawicki/http-request

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can find documentation on that version of `HTTPClient` [here](http://hc.apache.org/); it's especially useful to go through the [example scenarios](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-dev/examples.html) they present.

I unfortunately don't know version 3 of `HTTPClient` so I can't give direct equivalences; I suggest you take what you're trying to do and look through their example scenarios.

Comment: Thank you,
I will look at the documentation and I hope to find the solution of my problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
    package com.service.demo;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class WebServiceDemoActivity extends Activity 
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    private static String SOAP_ACTION1 = "http://tempuri.org/GetSubscriptionReportNames";//"http://tempuri.org/FahrenheitToCelsius";
    private static String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
    private static String METHOD_NAME1 = "GetSubscriptionReportNames";//"FahrenheitToCelsius";
    private static String URL = "http://icontrolusa.com:8040/iPhoneService.asmx?WSDL";

    Button btnFar,btnCel,btnClear;
    EditText txtFar,txtCel;
    ArrayList<String> headlist = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> reportlist = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        btnFar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnFar);
        btnCel = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCel);
        btnClear = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnClear);
        txtFar = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtFar);
        txtCel = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtCel);

        btnFar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                //Initialize soap request + add parameters
                SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME1);        

                //Use this to add parameters
                request.addProperty("Fahrenheit",txtFar.getText().toString());

                //Declare the version of the SOAP request
                SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

                envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                envelope.dotNet = true;

                try {
                    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

                    //this is the actual part that will call the webservice
                    androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION1, envelope);

                    // Get the SoapResult from the envelope body.
                    SoapObject result = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;

                    if(result != null)
                    {
                        //Get the first property and change the label text
                        txtCel.setText(result.getProperty(0).toString());
                        Log.e("err  ","output is ::::   "+result.getProperty(0).toString());

                        parseSON();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Response",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        btnClear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                txtCel.setText("");
                txtFar.setText("");
            }
        });
    }

    private void parseSON() {
            headlist.clear();
            reportlist.clear();
            String text = txtCel.getText().toString() ;//sb.toString();
            Log.i("######", "###### "+text);

            try{
                JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(text);   
                JSONArray  jarr = jobj.getJSONArray("Head");
                for(int i=0;i<jarr.length();i++){
                    JSONObject e = jarr.getJSONObject(i);
                    JSONArray names = e.names();
                    for(int j=0;j<names.length();j++){
                        String tagname = names.getString(j);
                        if (tagname.equals("ReportID")) {
                            headlist.add(e.getString("ReportID"));
                        }
                        if (tagname.equals("ReportName")) {
                            reportlist.add(e.getString("ReportName"));
                        }
                    }
                }    
            } catch(JSONException e){
                Log.e("retail_home", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
            }

            Log.d("length ", "head lenght "+headlist.size());
            Log.d("value is  ", "frst "+headlist.get(0));
            Log.d("length ", "name lenght "+reportlist.size());
            Log.d("value is  ", "secnd "+reportlist.get(0));

    }
}
```

Comment: ...but thanks for taking the time to post your code!