# Retrieving content of a txt file from URL to Android

Tags: java, android, text-files

I would like to be able to retrieve contents of a .txt file from the internet, and load it in an EditText. I tried using the code on this page: [Reading Text File From Server on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922210/reading-text-file-from-server-on-android)

It didn't work, as you might have guessed. I've read on numerous sites about this type of problem, but I can't get anything to work. Someone suggested [AndroidHttpClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/http/AndroidHttpClient.html) but I simply can't find any examples with this.

As I'm a newbie in Android programming, I would love if someone could please give me a small example.

Comment: What didn't work about it? Why should we have guessed that?

Comment: It actually works now, I don't know what was wrong before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't so much of an Android question as it is a Java question. There are a few ways you could go about doing this, but the simplest might be using `java.net.HttpURLConnection`.

Comment: Thanks. I can't seem to find any good examples on this though, can you help me out? As I said in the first post, I only need to retrieve contents from a simple .txt file.

Comment: Update: I was able to find a good example here: http://micropilot.tistory.com/category/Android/HttpClient%20example