# Android - InputStream not working correctly

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm trying to figure out why my inputstream isn't working correctly.  I am trying to connect to a server and get a JSON string and save it into the variable inputJSON. However inputJOSN is empty because my inputstream isn't working correctly.  This line of code:

```
 inputJSON = ConvertByteArrayToString(getBytesFromInputStream(inputStr));
```

doesn't seem to be working properly and I'm not sure why?

```
public class AndroidClient extends ProfileActivity {

private TextView textIn;

public Thread rt;
public Socket socket = null;
public PrintWriter outputstrwr;
public OutputStream out = null; 
public DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;
public DataInputStream dataInputStream = null;

public InputStream inputStr = null;

private final static String LOG_TAG = AndroidClient.class.getSimpleName();
private final Handler handler = new Handler();
private List<Profile> serviceInfoList = new ArrayList<Profile>();

// Map between list position and profile
private Map<Integer, Profile> posMap = new HashMap<Integer, Profile>();
private Map<String, Integer> addressMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

private static String profilePicBase64Str="";
private String inputJSON = "";
private String outputJSON = "";
private String outputJSONserv = "";
private Profile p;
//String urlInputStream = "";

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Before OnCreate() Try");
    try {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "In OnCreate() Try");
        socket = new Socket("23.23.175.213", 9000);  //Port 1337
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Created Socket");
        dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Created DataOutputStream");
        dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Created DataInputStream");

        //out = new OutputStream();
        out = socket.getOutputStream();
        inputStr = socket.getInputStream();

        //Thread readjsonthrd = new Thread(new ReadJSONThread());
        //inputstrrd = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());

        p = new Profile();
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Created Profile Instance");

        //Gets the local profile via JSON and converts into Profile type
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Created Gson Instance" + "GetProfileJSONStr:" + p.getProfileJSONStr());
        p = gson.fromJson(p.getProfileJSONStr(), Profile.class);
        setProfile(p);
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Converted Profile to JSON");

        //Gson gson = new Gson();
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Before: outputJSON = gson.toJson(p);");
        outputJSON = gson.toJson(p).toString();
        outputJSON = removeExcessStr(outputJSON);
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "ProfilePicStr Base64:"+p.getProfilePicStr());

        outputJSON = outputJSON.replace("Name","name");
        outputJSON = outputJSON.replace("TagLine","message");
        outputJSON = outputJSON.replace("Title","title");
        outputJSON = outputJSON.replace("Company", "company");
        outputJSON = outputJSON.replace("Industry","industry");
        outputJSON = outputJSON.replace("WhatIDo","whatido");
        outputJSON = outputJSON.replace("WhoDoIWantToMeet","meetwho");
        outputJSON = outputJSON.replace("WHOOZNEAR_PROFILEPIC","photo");
        outputJSON = outputJSON.replaceAll("[c][o][n][t][e][n][t][:][/][/][a-zA-Z0-9]+[/][a-zA-Z0-9]+[/][a-zA-Z0-9]+[/][a-zA-Z0-9]+[/][a-zA-Z0-9]+", getPicBase64Str()); /*"helloworld2"*/

        if (!outputJSON.contains(",\"photo\":")) { 
            outputJSON = outputJSON.replace("}",",\"photo\":"+"\"IconnexUs\"}");
            outputJSON = outputJSON.replace("}",",\"photo\":"+"\""+getPicBase64Str()+"\"}");
            outputJSON = outputJSON.replace("}",",\"status\":\"enabled\"}");
        }
        else { 
            outputJSON = outputJSON.replace("}",",\"status\":\"enabled\"");
        }

        outputJSONserv = "{\"to\":\"broadcast\",\"type\":\"1\",\"payload\":"+outputJSON+"}";

        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Created outputJSON:" + outputJSON);
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Created outputJSON Server:" + outputJSONserv);
        JSONObject outObject = new JSONObject();
        try {
            outObject.put("photo", "hello");
            outObject.put("type", "50");
            outObject.put("payload", outputJSON);
            outputJSON = gson.toJson(outObject).toString();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Value of PROFILEPIC STRING FROM PROFILEMAP: "+profileMap.get("WHOOZNEAR_PROFILEPIC"));
        p.setProfilePicStr(ConvertandSetImagetoBase64(profileMap.get("WHOOZNEAR_PROFILEPIC")));
        //String headerJSON = gson.toJson(outObject).toString();
        outputJSON = outputJSON.substring(nthOccurrence(outputJSON, '{', 2)-1, nthOccurrence(outputJSON, '}', 1)-1);

        String input = "["+"Ryan"+"[";
        //"[foo".replaceAll(Pattern.quote("["), "\""); 
        String result = input.replaceAll(Pattern.quote("["), "\"");
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "REGEX REPLACEALL:"+result);

        outputstrwr = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()), true);
        outputstrwr.write(outputJSONserv);

        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Base64 String:"+p.getProfilePicStr());
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Sent dataOutputStream");
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Before initEventHandlers");
    initEventHandlers();
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "After initEventHandlers");
    //refreshViewModels();

    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Start Repeat Thread");
    rt = new Thread(new RepeatingThread());
    rt.start();
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Started Repeat Thread");
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    rt.stop();
    try {
        socket.close();
        dataOutputStream.close();
        dataInputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    rt.stop();
}

@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    if (rt.isAlive() == false) {
        //rt.start();
    }
}

@Override
public void onStop(){
    super.onStop();
    rt.stop();
    try {
        socket.close();
        dataOutputStream.close();
        dataInputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public static String removeExcessStr(String json_excess) {      
    //String myString = myString.replace("=\"ppshein\"", "");
    String json_excess1 = json_excess.replace("\"nameValues\":{", "");
    String myString = json_excess1.replace(",\"profileId\":1,\"valid\":false}", "");
    return myString;
}
public static String adddblquotattr(String attr) { 
    String result = attr.replaceAll(Pattern.quote("["), "\"");
    return result;
}

public static String adddblquotval(String val) { 
    String result = val.replaceAll(Pattern.quote("["), "\"");
    return result;
}

public static int nthOccurrence(String str, char c, int n) {
    int pos = str.indexOf(c, 0);
    while (n-- > 0 && pos != -1)
        pos = str.indexOf(c, pos+1);
    return pos;
}

public void setPicBase64Str(String profilePicBase64Str) {
    this.profilePicBase64Str = profilePicBase64Str;
}

public String getPicBase64Str() {
    return profilePicBase64Str;
}

public String ConvertandSetImagetoBase64(String imagePath) { 
    String base64 = null;
    byte[] input = null;

    try{
        FileInputStream fd = new FileInputStream(imagePath);
        Bitmap bmt = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fd.getFD());

        try{                
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            Bitmap tmp = ProfileActivity.scaleDownBitmap(bmt, 10, this);
            tmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 10, stream);
            input = stream.toByteArray();
            base64 = Base64.encodeToString(input, Base64.DEFAULT);
            //LocalProfileActivity.input = input;
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e(LOG_TAG,"[ONACTIVITYRESULT] Could not bind input to the bytearray: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("LocalProfile", "ConvertandSetImagetoBase64: Could not load selected profile image");
    }
    return base64;
}

public String getStringFromBuffer(InputStreamReader inputstrread){
    BufferedReader bRead = new BufferedReader(inputstrread);
    String line = null;
    StringBuffer jsonText = new StringBuffer();
    try {
        while((line=bRead.readLine())!=null){
           jsonText.append(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return jsonText.toString();
}

public String ConvertByteArrayToString(byte[] b) { 
    // byte[] to string
    String input = new String(b);
    return input;
}

public byte[] ConvertStringToByteArray(String str) { 
    // string to byte[]
    byte[] bytes = str.getBytes();
    return bytes;
}

public static byte[] getBytesFromInputStream(InputStream is)
        throws IOException {

        // Get the size of the file
        long length = is.available();

        if (length > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
        // File is too large
        }

        // Create the byte array to hold the data
        byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) length];

        // Read in the bytes
        int offset = 0;
        int numRead = 0;
        while (offset < bytes.length
        && (numRead = is.read(bytes, offset, bytes.length - offset)) >= 0) {
        offset += numRead;
        }
        // Ensure all the bytes have been read in
        if (offset < bytes.length) {
        throw new IOException("Could not completely stream ");
        }
        // Close the input stream and return bytes
        is.close();
        return bytes;
}

public static String writeFile(Bitmap finalBitmap) { 
    String filePath = "";

    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File myDir = new File(root + "/saved_images");    
        myDir.mkdirs();
        Random generator = new Random();
        int n = 10000;
        n = generator.nextInt(n);
        String fname = "Image-"+ n +".jpg";
        File file = new File (myDir, fname);
        if (file.exists ()) file.delete (); 
        try {
               FileOutputStream outFile = new FileOutputStream(file);
               finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, outFile);
               outFile.flush();
               outFile.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
        }
    filePath = root+"/saved_images/"+fname;
    return filePath;
}

public class RepeatingThread implements Runnable {

     private final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
     private int len = 0; 


     private byte[] input = new byte[len];


     public RepeatingThread() {
         //try {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Before inputJSON String");
            //inputJSON = dataInputStream.readUTF();
            //URL url = new URL("tcp://23.23.175.213:1337");
            //inputJSON = dataInputStream.readUTF();
            //inputstrrd = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
            String hello = "hello world";
            //String inputJSON = getStringFromBuffer(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

            //Convert 
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "After inputJSON String:" + inputJSON); 
         /*}
         catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
         } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
         }*/

         //LOOK HERE FIRST  
         //inputJSON is what is received back from the server - Take the inputJSON 
         //String and use regular expressions HERE to remove all the other characters in the 
         //string except the payload JSON.
         //refreshViewModels(inputJSON);
     }

     @Override
     public void run() { 
          try {
              //outputstrwr.write(outputJSONserv);  //UNCOMMENT IF NEED TO SEND DATA TO GET JSON BACK
              inputJSON = ConvertByteArrayToString(getBytesFromInputStream(inputStr));
          } catch (IOException e) {
              // TODO Auto-generated catch block
              e.printStackTrace();
          }

          Log.e(LOG_TAG, "IN REPEATINGTHREAD-INPUTJSON:" + inputJSON);
          refreshViewModels(inputJSON);
          mHandler.postDelayed(this, 3000);       
     }
}

    public void refreshViewModels(String inputJSON) {

        try {
            ListView servicesListView = (ListView) this
                    .findViewById(R.id.profilesListView);

            String[] from = new String[] { "profilePic", "neighborName",
                    "tagLine" };
            int[] to = new int[] { R.id.avatar, R.id.username, R.id.email };

            // prepare the list of all records
            List<HashMap<String, Object>> fillMaps = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
            List<Profile> profiles = new ArrayList<Profile>();

            // Clear the position mapping list and reset it
            this.posMap.clear();
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "NEW inputJSON: " + inputJSON);
            inputJSON = getPayloadStr(inputJSON);
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "NEW inputJSON2: " + inputJSON);
            JSONArray profileArray = new JSONArray(inputJSON);

            for (int i=0; i<profileArray.length(); i++) { 
                JSONObject jsonObject = profileArray.getJSONObject(i);
                Gson gson = new Gson(); 
                Profile p = gson.fromJson(gson.toJson(jsonObject).toString(), Profile.class);
                profiles.add(p);
            }

            int pos = 0;

            // Creates the fillMaps list for the listAdapter
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Profiles size: " + profiles.size());
            //showToast("Profiles size: " + profiles.size());
            for (Profile p : profiles) {
                // Create mapping for list adapter
                HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                map.put("profilePic",
                        p.getAttributeValue("photo")== null? "Not Set" : p
                                .getAttributeValue("photo"));
                map.put("neighborName",
                        p.getAttributeValue("Name") == null? "Not Set" : p
                                .getAttributeValue("Name"));
                map.put("tagLine",
                        p.getAttributeValue("TagLine") == null? "Not Set" : p
                                .getAttributeValue("TagLine"));
                fillMaps.add(map);

                // Reset the postion mapping
                this.posMap.put(pos++, p);

            }

            ListAdapter servicesListAdapter = new myAdapter(this, fillMaps,
                    R.layout.listitem, from, to);
            servicesListView.setAdapter(servicesListAdapter);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error making list adapter: " + e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    public String getPayloadStr(String profileString) {
        Log.e("LOG_TAG", "Profile Str:"+profileString);
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*?payload\":(.*)\\}");

        Log.e("LOG_TAG", "I got here 1");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(profileString);
        Log.e("LOG_TAG", "I got here 12");
        //Matcher m = responseCodePattern.matcher(firstHeader);
        matcher.matches();
        matcher.groupCount();
        //matcher.group(0);
        Log.e("LOG_TAG", "I got here 2"+matcher.group(1));
        return matcher.group(1);
    }


     private class myAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {

            public myAdapter(Context context, List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data,
                    int resource, String[] from, int[] to) {
                super(context, data, resource, from, to);

            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                if (convertView == null) {
                    convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listitem,
                            null);
                }

                HashMap<String, Object> data = (HashMap<String, Object>) getItem(position);

                ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.username))
                        .setText((String) data.get("neighborName"));

                ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.email))
                .setText((String) data.get("tagLine"));


                // Convert a string representing an image back to an image
                String base64 = ((String)data.get("profilePic"));
                byte[] picBytes = Base64.decode(base64, Base64.DEFAULT);  
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(picBytes, 0, picBytes.length);


                //THE IF AND THE ELSE NEED TO BE SWITCHED
                if (bitmap==null){
                    ((ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.avatar)).setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_whooznear);
                }else{
                    ((ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.avatar)).setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                }

                return convertView;
            }

        }

     public void callProfileActivity(int position)
     { 
         // Catch the case when service info is empty
         if(serviceInfoList.size()==0){
             return;
         }
         Profile profClick = posMap.get(position);
         String b64Str = profClick.getAttributeValue("photo");

         Intent startViewActivity = new Intent();
         startViewActivity.putExtra("TransProfile", (Profile)posMap.get(position));
         startViewActivity.putExtra("PhotoBase64", b64Str);
         if(serviceInfoList.size()>position){
             //DO SOMETHING HERE
         }else{
             Log.e(LOG_TAG,"Profile doesn't exist in sevice infoList? Selecting first one");
         }
         startViewActivity.setClass(this, ViewProfileActivity.class);
         startActivity(startViewActivity);
     }
    /**
     * Initialize the event handlers
     */
    public void initEventHandlers() {
        // Service List View
        ListView servicesListView = (ListView) this
                .findViewById(R.id.profilesListView);
        servicesListView
                .setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v,
                            int position, long id) {
                        Profile clickedProfile = posMap.get(position);
                        //showToast("Clicked Pos: " + position);

                        /*Intent intent = new Intent(ConnectActivity.this, ViewProfileActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("ClickProfile", posMap.get(position));*/

                        callProfileActivity(position);  
                    }
                });
    }

    /*@Override 
    public void onBackPressed() { // do something on back.
         super.onBackPressed();
         Intent myIntent = new Intent(AndroidClient.this, ProfileActivity.class);
         startActivity(myIntent);
         return; 
    }*/
}
```

Comment: Define 'isn't working correctly' and 'doesn't seem to be working properly'.

Comment: The listview is not populating because the inputstream is not getting any data back from the server.  The line of code: inputJSON = ConvertByteArrayToString(getBytesFromInputStream(inputStr));  is not getting data back from the server.  I think there is something wrong with my getBytesFromInputStream() method but I'm not sure what?  I'm trying to read bytes from the server with that method.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is rather long, so I cannot be sure of what exactly is the problem, but there is definitely an issue here:

```
public static byte[] getBytesFromInputStream(InputStream is)
    throws IOException {

    // Get the size of the file
    long length = is.available();
```

If you are calling this right after sending your URL request, the server may not have had time to send the result back, so `is.available()` may return zero or another value less than the actual number of bytes you would hope would be available. Try [code like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2922340/1270789) for reading in the file.

Comment: It's not a file it's a stream from a server

Comment: @user268397 Doesn't make any difference. It's a misuse of available() to use it to try to predict the entire length of any stream, and the Javadoc contains a specific warning that says so.

Comment: What should I use to get the length then?

Comment: Can't I just get data from the server without sending it anything?  How can I accomplish that in my code?

Comment: @user268397 You have to send a GET request to the server to start reading the data. Your code (presumably) already does that, so use the code I linked to to read in the data instead. You'll maybe need to change the return type of `getBytesFromInputStream()` to `String`, but otherwise the rest of the code can be left alone.