# How to read text from downloaded text file directly from an application?

Tags: android, android-webview, android-wifi

I am implementing reading text file from an external SDcard through Wifi.
Now I can download text files from SDcard at my android app. 
My questions are :

(1) How can I read text directly from the text files into my app?
What i am doing is i am scanning all attached devices and choose the SDcard to see the contents through a url. The url is has ip address and port number of the attached SDCard.
then i can see the files and the current status is just to download the file into the download folder.
What i want is read directly the text from the text files. so that I don't need to download.
Is it possible?

If not possible,

(2) Catch those downloaded text into my application directly so that i don't need one more step to get text from the text file in the download folder.
May I have some suggestion? My intention is to read text files from the SDcard into my application.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to read the text file without downloading it.
Since you have the direct url to your textfile you can just access it and read it like [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922210/reading-text-file-from-server-on-android)

Comment: So I need to scan all urls in the Webview first to see what are available to download. Thanks.

Comment: I suppose that you can get the html of your webview the parse it and get all the urls, I don't know much about what you are developing but I thing that you should be more specific on the decription of your problem above. Thanks

Comment: Now I tried to get url of the text file when the user click the url using public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url). Thanks