# How to load text from url?

Tags: android, url, bufferedinputstream

I want to load text from URL, store to string and append the loaded text to  `String image_url = "http://example.com/example" + yourData;` as shown below.
I cannot get the data from txt file and append in another URL. Help needed. Thanks!

```
try {
    // Create a URL for the desired page
    URL url = new URL("example.com/thefile.txt");

    // Read all the text returned by the server
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    String str;
    while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
        // str is one line of text; readLine() strips the newline character(s)
        builder.append(str);
    }

    in.close();
    String yourData = builder.toString();
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
} catch (IOException e) {
}

// Loader image - will be shown before loading image
int loader = R.drawable.loader;
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
String image_url = "http://example.com/example" + yourData;
ImageLoader imgLoader = new ImageLoader(getApplicationContext());
imgLoader.DisplayImage(image_url, loader, image);
```

Comment: You need to use an `AsyncTask` to grab data from a URL. See [Make an HTTP request with android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505930/make-an-http-request-with-android)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading Text File From Server on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922210/reading-text-file-from-server-on-android)

Comment: and make sure your code does not throw `MalformedURLException`.

Comment: New in android. can i get the edited code please!

Answer (score 0):

Use `Properties` class

For more details

https://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/read-data-from-properties-file-using-java-selenium