# Post data to server in android

Tags: android, post, cookies

I want to send some data to a server through POST method in android. I am using the following code

```
DefaultHttpClient hc=new DefaultHttpClient();  
ResponseHandler <String> res=new BasicResponseHandler();  
HttpPost postMethod=new HttpPost(url); 
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2); 
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", "value"));     
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "value"));    
postMethod.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));    
String response=hc.execute(postMethod,res);
```

But I am getting the error response in my response xml. The error message is cookies are disabled in client machine. How do I need to enable cookies in android ?

Comment: please put your codes in code block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to handle cookies with your request. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/678630/how-do-i-make-an-http-request-using-cookies-on-android) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3587254/how-do-i-manage-cookies-with-httpclient-in-android-and-or-java) related questions.

Comment: Hello friend, I am getting cookies size is 0 when i print the cookie using the getCookie method of CookieStore object. May I know where to find the cookie values and how to set those values while sending the request. Even if I use the sample given there, I am getting the same response "cookies are disabled in client machine" in my response xml body.