# How to use session to work between php webservices and android

Tags: php, android, web-services, session

I have an android application which uses php webservices. I have created the login.php which will validates the username, password sent from the android application. Once validated, a session is created such as follows:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['userId'] = $id;
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
```

On the client-side I have this:

```
HttpContext httpContext = new BasicHttpContext();
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost, httpContext);
HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
```

When I debug, I see that the httpReponse contains a PHPSESSID. I do know that I will need this information for comparison between the session_id on the server-side before executing any queries.

However, I do not know how to retrieve this "Set-Cookie" and send it to the server-side for comparison? A piece of code or tutorial will be extremely helpful.

Thank you

Comment: Would you mind posting the response that that is returned? My best guess is that is just a JSON object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3587254/how-do-i-manage-cookies-with-httpclient-in-android-and-or-java) answer for a solution.
HttpClient supports cookies by default and you will have to enable them so that php sessions work.

Comment: Thanks for the example.I managed to retrieve the String value of the PHPSESSID. Now, how do I do to compare this value to the opened session on the server? Is there some php code that I need to write?

Comment: You can see a basic example of sessions in php manual http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php.
What are you trying to do exactly ?
Can you share some of your code ?

Comment: I want to make sure if the open session_id on the server_side is the same as the client_side. So, for example - I have this "d9fq1lrd8t0bn9fkfmgdc1oj36" retrieved as a cookie from a HTTPResponse. Now, I will use this string and compare it with the session_id on the server to verify if the user is logged in. But I cannot seem to figure out how to do it.