# How to stay logged in using a HttpClient on Android?

Tags: android, httpresponse, androidhttpclient

I have a problem with Androids HttpClient / HttpRequest that's really giving me headache.
The program should login on a website (it's actually working and login is successful). After it's logged in, I want it to get another path of the site, but I don't know how to stay logged in for the next call. The site is using cookies and i tried four different examples that i found on stackoverflow, but nothing helped me.
The code I have is:

```
    HttpClient loginclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost loginpost = new HttpPost("EXAMPLEURL");

    //Parameters
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cookieuser", "1"));
    nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("vb_login_username", "EXAMPLE"));
    nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("vb_login_password", "EXAMPLE"));
    nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("do", "login"));
    nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("submit", "anmelden"));

    // Url Encoding the POST parameters
    try {
        loginpost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
    }

    // Making HTTP Request
    try {
        HttpResponse response = loginclient.execute(loginpost);

        String responseString = new BasicResponseHandler().handleResponse(response);
        System.out.println(responseString);

    }
```

PS: I removed the catch statements to make the code more clear

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I manage cookies with HttpClient in Android and/or Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3587254/how-do-i-manage-cookies-with-httpclient-in-android-and-or-java)