# Doing HTTP Post with Android

Tags: android

I need to pass some values to a URL by Post Method in my apllication. Please Help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's some code that will make an HTTP POST request.  Taken from http://androidadvice.blogspot.com/2010/10/httppost-request.html, which has some additional explanation as well.

```
HttpClient httpclient =  new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(Constants.MAIN_URL);
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("u", eUsername));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("p", ePassword));
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client/). See a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874227/android-project-using-httpclient-http-client-apache-post-get-method).