# how to send data to server through api in android?

Tags: android, http

I'm implementing an app on android platform with web services. I'm able to fetch data from server through api. Now I want to send data to server through api. I didn't get proper code, Please let me know the standard code for this or any example for it.

Thanks,
Vishakha.

Comment: There is no "standard code" - only several standard grammars. Get some docs from the service provider.

Answer (score 0):

Which kind of server? What kind of information? Without more info it's difficult to help.

I'm assuming you wish to make a POST request to a webserver. If this is the case, you might want to try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3912494/doing-http-post-with-android) answer.

Comment: I want to send data to web server api is given. By using that only I have to send data like sending lat,lon in http url for example

Comment: example  : in the following url sendin message through api given as follows  "http://webserver.com/api?location=35.0,47.0&message=msg"

Comment: This is still not enough information. This describes that you have to do a http GET request, but not how to interpret the answer.