# How transfer messages from web service to android client?

Tags: android, wcf, web-services

can you tell me How transfer messages from web service to android client?. 
It's available?
Example: a client send message A to service .... then i want service send this message to all client using..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need this [using kSoap](http://codeoncloud.blogspot.com/2012/04/android-403-webservice-access-tutorial.html) or you can make your own webservice using PHP.hopefully use for you :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking this [Doing HTTP Post with Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3912494/doing-http-post-with-android)

You can use HttpClient component from apache.