# Android HttpClient Cookie

Tags: android, cookies, authentication, httpclient

Does Android HttpClient has auto-management for cookies?

Answer (score 6):

It does support it.

Reading the posts below it seems like you have to pass the same HttpContext when calling execute.

```
response = httpClient.execute(httpPost,localContext);
```

exactly how to do is in this post: [Android project using httpclient --> http.client (apache), post/get method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874227/android-project-using-httpclient-http-client-apache-post-get-method/903387#903387)

[How do I manage cookies with HttpClient in Android and/or Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3587254/how-do-i-manage-cookies-with-httpclient-in-android-and-or-java)

Answer (score 0):

You can make it static and use it in all requests

```
client =  new OkHttpClient();  // client will be static and use in all requests 

CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager();
cookieManager.setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);
client.setCookieHandler(cookieManager);
```