# Posting XML data to server from android?

Tags: android, xml, android-xml

I try to send the data from my application to server in xml format in android , any one could suggest some method and example to post the data to server.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried to perform a search?

- [Http Post in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874227/android-project-using-httpclient-http-client-apache-post-get-method)
- [Android, sending XML via HTTP POST (SOAP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559948/android-sending-xml-via-http-post-soap)
- [Http post in Java](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=java&seqNum=44)
- [Http post in Java with UrlConnection](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.net/post.html)
- [HttpClient android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html)