# send json string as request to server using https connection

Tags: android

In my android application i would like to send a json object with username and password as string to the server.
Could you please let me know how i can achieve this using https connection.

Please share your valuable suggestions.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried a search?

- [Http Post in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874227/android-project-using-httpclient-http-client-apache-post-get-method)
- [Android, sending XML via HTTP POST (SOAP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559948/android-sending-xml-via-http-post-soap)
- [Http post in Java](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=java&seqNum=44)
- [Http post in Java with UrlConnection](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.net/post.html)
- [HttpClient android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html)

Comment: I think @Remmyabhavan wants to know how to work with HTTPS and is a little different. All your links points to "regular" Http posts.

Comment: @seretur I have successfully used the `HttpClient` for HTTPS connections & POSTs with few issues.  The main stumbling block would be if the site certificate has not been signed by an authority that Android recognises.  Also `UrlConnection` has a sub-class of `HttpsURLConnection` that I have also used with success.

Comment: Yes, that's why i said it, you mention Android and self-signed SSL and i start walking on the roof pulling my hair off :).