# Android: soap request with DefaultHttpClient

Tags: android, soap

would you please provide me with a method to make a soap request using Android's **DefaultHttpClient**

thanks

Answer (score 2):

SOAP is XML exchange over HTTP. So besides a `DefaultHttpClient` you need something to parse the higher-level XML exchange.

I suggest you use [Ksoap 2](http://ksoap2.sourceforge.net/). Here is a android jar: http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/wiki/HowToUse

Here is an example of using ksoap: http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/using-ksoap2-android-and-parsing-output-data

Comment: Thanks peter, but I don't want to use Ksoap2. I need to use the default android client

Comment: Then you will need to implement the soap protocol and parse/produce XML in your code.

Comment: Ok, no problem in parsing, I just need to know how to send the envelop

Comment: Something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/874227/android-project-using-httpclient-http-client-apache-post-get-method/903387#903387