# How to send a data to a web server from Android

Tags: php, android

I want to send data to my php page using android. How can I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make GET or POST requests using [AndroidHttpClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/http/AndroidHttpClient.html):

1. Create an [AndroidHttpClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/http/AndroidHttpClient.html) to execute your requests.
2. Create either an [HttpGet](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpGet.html) or [HttpPost](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpPost.html) request.
3. Use [setEntity](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase.html#setEntity%28org.apache.http.HttpEntity%29) and [setHeader](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/HttpMessage.html#setHeader%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) methods to populate the request.
4. Use one of the [execute](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/http/AndroidHttpClient.html#execute%28org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest%29) methods on your client with your request.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874227/android-project-using-httpclient-http-client-apache-post-get-method/903387#903387) seems like a fairly complete code sample.

Answer (score 12):

The Android API has a set of functions that allows you to use HTTP requests, POST, GET etc.
In this example i will provide a set of code that will allow you to update the contents of a file in a server using POST requests.

Our server side code will be very simple and it will be written in PHP.
The code will get data from a post request, update a file with the data and load this file to display it in a browser.

Create PHP page on server "mypage.php", the code for php page is:-

```
 <?php

 $filename="datatest.html";
 file_put_contents($filename,$_POST["fname"]."<br />",FILE_APPEND);
 file_put_contents($filename,$_POST["fphone"]."<br />",FILE_APPEND);
 file_put_contents($filename,$_POST["femail"]."<br />",FILE_APPEND);
 file_put_contents($filename,$_POST["fcomment"]."<br />",FILE_APPEND);
 $msg=file_get_contents($filename);
 echo $msg; ?>
```

Create Android Project and write below code in HTTPExample.java

```
           HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
       HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://example.com/mypage.php");
         try {
       List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(4);

       nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fname", "vinod"));
       nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fphone", "1234567890"));
       nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("femail", "abc@gmail.com"));
       nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fcomment", "Help"));
       httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
       httpclient.execute(httppost);

     } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     } catch (IOException e) {
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     }
```

Add permission in AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: i have Do with ur code there are problem unfortunately closed  i have completely insert permit-ion of internet....can u add more in your code ....why i getting error and  values are not going to server....

Answer (score 4):

A quick example for a HTTP POST request is given here:

```
try {
    // Construct data
    String data = URLEncoder.encode("key1", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("value1", "UTF-8");
    data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("key2", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("value2", "UTF-8");

    // Send data
    URL url = new URL("http://hostname:80/cgi");
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
    wr.write(data);
    wr.flush();

    // Get the response
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        // Process line...
    }
    wr.close();
    rd.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
}
```