# Retrieve data from android app to PHP website

Tags: php, android

Is there any method to get data from an Android app to a website?

If it is from website to website, with "*file_get_contents*" it is possible. But then any idea on getting data from Android apps?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Using this simple php script you can get data from android:

```
<?php

$filename="datatest.html";
file_put_contents($filename,$_POST["fname"]."<br />",FILE_APPEND);
file_put_contents($filename,$_POST["fphone"]."<br />",FILE_APPEND);
file_put_contents($filename,$_POST["femail"]."<br />",FILE_APPEND);
file_put_contents($filename,$_POST["fcomment"]."<br />",FILE_APPEND);
$msg=file_get_contents($filename);
echo $msg; ?>
```

In android can use `HttpPost` to accomplish this by something like this:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
   HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://example.com/mypage.php");
     try {
   List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(4);

   nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fname", "jake"));
   nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fphone", "9999999"));
   nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("femail", "xyz@live.com"));
   nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fcomment", "Help"));
   httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
   httpclient.execute(httppost);

 } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
 } catch (IOException e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
 }
```

Replace your data with the fields you want to set and send in the constructor of `BasicNameValuePair`.

Here is the actual [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5666109/how-to-send-a-data-to-a-web-server-from-android)

Comment: what do you mean you may not have access to the source code of app ? you want to make a website which gets data from android system ?

Comment: Partially yes, getting or knowing latest news from the app.

Answer (score 0):

You could [execute post requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938502/sending-post-data-in-android) in android to your website. Although this has to executed from a different thread, since android doesn't allow [network operations on the main thread.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html)

Comment: here android app in the sense, any android app. I may not have access to the source code of that app. Like I said, inside "file_get_contents" I can give any web address. Same way, any general method?