# Android how to store a "string" on a webpage?

Tags: android, web-services, web, android-layout

So I want to store a string on my website and then have my app download it, so I could use it in a layout. How could I do that? I there a way I can take html files and have android read that text? or can I store a .txt and have android convert that to a string?
Thanks

Comment: You have to be more specific. Provide an example of what you are having a problem with.

Comment: What kind of software do you have on run your website?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you could just put the string inside of a file that your web server will serve up for you (maybe omit the extension altogether).  You can then download it from an android app using the file's url.

It seems like you might want to look into [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Json), it will facilitate storing structured data instead of just a string.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874227/android-project-using-httpclient-http-client-apache-post-get-method) is an example of downloading a url from an Android program.